# create-react-app testing "React is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

I am using `react-scripts@2.1.8` with `typescript@3.3.3` with `jest@.23.6.0` and running my tests, they fail with "React is not defined".

```
 FAIL  src/components/Button/test.tsx
  ● <Button> › renders text correctly

    ReferenceError: React is not defined

       6 |     it('renders text correctly', () => {
       7 |         const text = 'hello there i am a test'
    >  8 |         const { getByText } = customRender(<Button>{text}</Button>)
         |                                            ^
       9 |         expect(getByText(/hello there i am a test/)).toBeTruthy()
      10 |     })
      11 |     it('matches the snapshot', () => {

      at Object.it (src/components/Button/test.tsx:8:44)

  ● <Button> › matches the snapshot

    ReferenceError: React is not defined

      10 |     })
      11 |     it('matches the snapshot', () => {
    > 12 |         const { container } = customRender(<Button />)
         |                                            ^
      13 |         expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot()
      14 |     })
      15 | })

      at Object.it (src/components/Button/test.tsx:12:44)
```

Button.test.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '.'
import { customRender } from '../../test-utils'

describe('<Button>', () => {
    it('renders text correctly', () => {
        const text = 'hello there i am a test'
        const { getByText } = customRender(<Button>{text}</Button>)
        expect(getByText(/hello there i am a test/)).toBeTruthy()
    })
    it('matches the snapshot', () => {
        const { container } = customRender(<Button />)
        expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
})
```

Also playing with React import, like moving it from line 1 to line 3 seems to sometimes make the tests pass. Which is very strange.

Comment: What does `import Button from '.'` do?

Comment: It was VSCode's auto import. It's importing from index. So `import Button from './index'`.

Comment: if I use `import Button from './index'` it actually fixes this test, but other tests break. I seem to have to migrate `import React, { useContext} from 'react'` into `import React from 'react'` and then use `React.useContext` or do `import * as React` :/

Comment: So running the test on CI it passed. I made an unrelated change to the CI script, and now the tests fail again. Very strange :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the jsx pragma and emotion 10 as discussed and explained in [this issue](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1303).